# Why i get error when call oracle procedure with c#?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm write this procedure into the oracle 11g:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE LOG_IN(P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2,
                 P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2,
                 P_LOGIN_RESULT OUT LOGINRESULT) IS
  LV_LOGIN_RESULT LOGINRESULT;
BEGIN
  LOG_WRITER_BILL(NULL, 'LOGIN', 'MODULE START', 'START');
  LV_LOGIN_RESULT := LOGINRESULT(NULL,
                                 NULL);
  LV_LOGIN_RESULT.SESSIONID := WEBSERVICE_API_PKG.LOGIN(P_USERNAME,
                                                        P_PASSWORD);
  IF LV_LOGIN_RESULT.SESSIONID IS NULL THEN
    LV_LOGIN_RESULT.RESULT:= 1;
  ELSE
    LV_LOGIN_RESULT.RESULT := 0;
  END IF;
  LOG_WRITER_BILL(NULL, 'LOGIN', 'MODULE END', 'END');
  P_LOGIN_RESULT := LV_LOGIN_RESULT;
END;
```

and into the this line `P_LOGIN_RESULT OUT LOGINRESULT` i declare the object with this:

```
create or replace
TYPE LOGINRESULT AS OBJECT 
( 
  Result NUMBER,
  SessionID NUMBER
);
```

and i write this code into the c# for run that code:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("User Id=WEBSERVICE_ACCESS;Password=DAMAVAND;Server=ORA11;");
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "LOG_IN";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("P_USERNAME", "guest").Direction=ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("P_PASSWORD", "guest").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Result", OracleType.Number, 20).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("SessionID", OracleType.Number, 20).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;  
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["Result"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Connection.Close();
```

but when i run that code i get this error:
[image]

What happen?

Answer (score 0):

In the procedure, there is only one out parameter, `P_LOGIN_RESULT`. In the call in C# you have two parameters, `Result` and `SessionId`.

Comment: thanks my friend,but P_LOGIN_RESULT is object and into the that object i have a two parameter,Result and SessionId,Can i call direct P_LOGIN_RESULT?

Comment: Yes, and you should to comply with the procedure signature.

Comment: Thanks for help me and pay attention to my problem,can you write me c# code for your solution?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("SessionID", OracleType.Number, 20).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;  i write this but i get same error.

Comment: The name of the parameter is `P_LOGIN_RESULT`, right?

Comment: P_LOGIN_RESULT is my object and include SessionID  (number) and Result (number)

Comment: I know. What is your question?

Comment: How can i call that object?

Comment: Or How can i get data from that object?